# ibus doesn't work in libreoffice, pluma etc in Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, keyboard-layout, mate, ibus

I have iBus with Sanskrit (IAST) and Bengali layouts. Besides that I have English and Russian keyboard layouts. iBus works in other applications (Firefox, Thunderbird), but doesn't work at all in Writer, Pluma, SublimeText, Atom etc. It used to work some weeks ago. Any suggestion?

Comment: You have chosen `ibus` as  `Keyboard input method system` at `Language Support` right? What do you mean doesn't work, it doesn't switch keyboard layout? Also with what keyboard combination do you switch layouts?

Comment: Yes, I set ibus as a Keyboard input method system. "Doesn't work" means when I switch to ibus and want to type Bengali characters nothing changes and I can only type Roman characters. I switch layouts with Shift+CapsLock.

Comment: Just typed some Bangla characters in LO Writer on (an updated) Ubuntu MATE, so what you describe is not a general issue. (I used _ibus-m17n_).

Comment: I don't use ibus but try to restore to default settings by deleting if there is any `~/.config/ibus` or `~/.ibus` or some similar folder (press ctrl+h at file manager to see hidden files). Then reboot.

Comment: I deleted ibus completely, then deleted `/usr/share/m17n/` and `~/.config/ibus`, however when I install it again it shows up with my previously selected languages! So the settings are still kept somewhere, but I don't know where!

Comment: I also tried `ibus reset-config`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Okay, it seems that I figured out where the settings hide - `dconf/desktop/ibus`. I cleaned it with `dconf reset -f /desktop/ibus/`. Then I reinstalled `ibus` and nothing changed. Finally I tried the tip from the ArchLinux page https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBus#LibreOffice. Amazingly, it worked! And it works even when LO is started not from the terminal! 

However, I HAVE ANOTHER PROBLEM! Whenever I type a letter that can be modified (e.g. "a" which when typed twice "aa" becomes "ā"), Ibus strangely inserts the following letter before it! So when I type "kala" it becomes "kla a"!

Comment: @brijabasi, You better write that an answer. for `a` issue may be the current layout you are using, has `a` as dead key. it means you have to enter `a` then *space* to get simple `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you switched to Lubuntu? 
Maybe you could have some trouble if you have got it. 
Moreover maybe you have installed some apps that have
deleted some libs linked to ibus. Remove all with

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ibus-*
```

Re install from beginning.

Comment: No, I didn't use Lubuntu in any way. Reinstall doesn't help.

Comment: Also I noticed a strange dependency - whenever I quit ibus my Firefox crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check

1. Libre Office → Tools → Options...
2. Language Settings → Languages → Unchecked: Ignore system input system.